# Backbone index-route causing window to scroll up

Tags: backbone.js, scroll, routes

I'm having an issue with Backbone.js. If I came from a route (say `site.com#services/strategy`), and I navigate back to my index-view (`site.com#`), I'm sent back to the top of the document. I understand why this works that way, but I'd like to prevent this. Is there a known / recommended way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Store/restore the current scroll position before/after navigation...

Comment: I had considered that, but it feels 'hacky'. I can't imagine I'm the first guy to run into this behavior...

Comment: Also: it causes a weird flash...

Comment: And by weird flash I mean a very explainable flash: for an instant you see the top of the page before getting moved back down again...